# How to use collect_set in hive query

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

I have a table in `hive` like below

```
id   name  sal
1    sam   2000
2    Ram   3000
3    Tim   4000
4    Ash   5000
```

I want to get all the values from the column `name` as a variable.

I have done like below

```
abc=`hive -e "select distinct name from db.tbl";`
```

when I do like below

```
echo $abc
```

The result I get is

```
Ash Ram Tim sam
```

I want the result to be like

```
'Ash', 'Ram', 'Tim', 'sam'
```

I tried like below

```
xyz=`hive -e "select concat_ws(',', collect_set(name)) from from db.tbl";`

echo $xyz

Ash,sam,Ram,Tim
```

I idea here is that I want to use the variable in `where in clause`

what I want to achieve is below

```
select * from db.tbl where name in (variable)
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query

```
xyz=`hive -e "select concat_ws(',', collect_set(name)) from from db.tbl";`
```

Add double quotes before and after each items of the variable

```
xyz_list=echo "\"${xyz//,/\",\"}\""
```

Query the variable

```
echo $xyz_list

"Ash", "Ram", "Tim", "sam"
```

Desired query

```
hive -e "select * from db.tbl where name in ($xyz_list)";
```

Another way to achieve your result

```
abc=`hive -e "select collect_set(concat_ws(',', name)) from db.tbl";`

test=${abc:1:-1}

hive -e "select * from db.tbl where name in ($test)";
```